# fsresource - runmode config stored in crx via xml

Tags: osgi, aem, crx

i'm using the fsresource sling extension to access the filesystem when working on JSP, JS, CSS and so on. When just yanking the bundle into the crx and configuring it via the OSGi console, everything works as expected. But when i try to add a new runmode (configurtion), the result is unsatisfying.

```
config/src/main/content/jcr_root/apps/samples/config/org.apache.sling.fsprovider.internal.FsResourceProvider.factory.config.xml
```

Is the path of the main configuration, which i'm using on a local instance to figure out, how to achieve the desired results, but the best i could get was an unbound configuration displayed in the

```
system/console/configMgr
```

The contents of the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0"     
          xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
          jcr:primaryType="sling:OsgiConfig"
          provider.roots="/apps/ui-samples"
          provider.file="/Volumes/samples/ui/src/main/content/jcr_root/apps/ui-samples"
          provider.checkinterval="1000"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the i just thought too complicated about the name of the file.

```
org.apache.sling.fsprovider.internal.FsResourceProvider-samples.xml
```

for instance does the job.